# Can I extend cloth cable with romex?

Tags: electrical

I have a house from 1960s. I need to extend a cloth covered wire (contains hot, neutral and ground wire). Can it be safely done with a romex 12/2? This is for a light bulb.

So I just wire the respective wires together (hot-hot, neutral-neutral, ground-ground) with wirenut and that's it? This will be in my attic so I'm not sure if I should leave connecting wires exposed like this and in contact with insulation. Electric tape the wires/wire items too?

Comment: No, absolutely not. You need to follow code, and there is a lot of it. You have to secure the romex outside of & near a box, the terminations have to be inside of a box and the box accessible. If you are working in the attic already, you should run new. You cant just lay romex loosely, etc.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Sorry for asking such a dumb question. In this case, I guess I’ll just work with the existing clothed cable to install the recessed can. Running new romex from junction box to light fixture will have to be a future project for me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If the wire is copper, you can mount an electrical box in the attic and use wire nuts to join the old and new same gauge wiring. If you are joining old aluminum wiring to new copper wiring, call an electrician so you don't burn your house down. :)

Comment: Thanks! Didn’t even think of mounting a box up here.

Comment: The junction box must remain accessible, it can't be buried where you need tools or to disassemble any part of the building to get to it.  You also need strain reliefs /clamps where any cable enters the box.

Comment: not to mention he should check the capacity of the circuit. The more current you draw on an old circuit, the more opportunity there is for a problem. This is one of those things that is WORTH it to rewire vs. reusing.